# Datagridview row bottom font gets cropped while editing

Tags: winforms

[image: Sample datagridview]

I am using datagridview C++ Winforms. The 2nd row is being editted, which causes the underscore before "SV" to be cropped out. I tried increasing the row height, but the bottom part of the font being edited will still get cropped out, making the use unable to see the underscore while editing the cell. How do I avoid the font getting cropped while editing?

Comment: Don't use `Microsoft Sans Serif` as Font, use `Segoe UI` (should be set as default in place of the former) or `Microsoft YaHei UI` -- The `UI` suffix gives away the reason why those Fonts were created.

Comment: That solved my issue. Thanks a lot